# Как правильно добавить анимацию к блоку (CSS, SASS)

Tags: html, css, html5, sass

Не пойму пойму почему свойство `transition: all .2s ease` не работает в данной конструкции:
HTML

```
<div class="portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio-item photo">
    <img src="img/photo/001.jpg" alt="Photo 1">
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-item website">
    <div class="portfolio-info">
      <span class="info">
        <h3>Название проекта</h3>
        <p>Web-сайт</p>
        <hr>
        <a class="far fa-hand-point-right" href="#">
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <img src="img/photo/001.jpg" alt="Photo 1">
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.portfolio
  line-height: 0
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  &-item
    flex: 1
    position: relative
    flex-basis: calc(400px)
    &:hover .portfolio-info
      display: -webkit-flex
      display: -moz-flex
      display: -ms-flex
      display: -o-flex
      display: flex   
  &-info
    display: none
    transition: all .2s ease
    background-color: rgba($active-color, 0.9)
    position: absolute
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    color: $white
    font-size: 1.48rem
    font-weight: 400
    text-align: center
    flex-direction: column
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство display не поддается анимации. Используй костыли с opacity, visible и height или width на крайний случай.